# CLion Boost library

Tags: c++, windows, boost, cmake, clion

I have installed Boost library following these commands:

1. I have extracted downloaded `boost_1_67_0.7z`file
2. Then I have executed command `bootstrap.bat gcc`
3. Then I executed command `b2 install --prefix=c:/Boost toolset=gcc`
4. Then I restared my computer, just in case

Then I have opened CLion (newest version) and tried to include boost library in my program with `find_package(Boost)`, but that doesn't work for me. Am I doing something wrong here or there is some other problem?

[CMake file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouqXD.png)

[Source code for my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMIAc.png)

[Folder hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUSPO.png)

Also I tried to say CMake whereis Boost installed with command

`set(BOOST_ROOT C:/Boost/include/boost-1_67)`

Then CMake can [detect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JSPD.png) Boost, but it doesn't want to compile because it 
[can't find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/512ZI.png) any file, for example `boost/thread.hpp`.

Comment: There is not enough information in the body of this question to help you. Images are okay as *supplemental* resources, but if they are fundamental to the question, then they should not be images. The CMakeLists.txt, project structure, and Boost installation directory are all important to this question, so they should be directly in the question

Comment: You named your project and your executable `Boost`. I don't think this is a good idea. It's probably better to name it something like `TestingBoost`

Comment: I believe the root of the problem is that CMake just doesn't know where Boost is. Try editing the command to run cmake to have `-DBOOST_ROOT=C:/Boost/include/boost-1_67/` or something like that.

Comment: Dependency management is much easier with a package manager such as [Conan](https://conan.io/) or [vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/)

Comment: @Justin how can I give more helpful informations? I already showed images where I installed Boost

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. Your question needs to be able to stand alone without the images. Pretend that the image links don't exist. If you do so, there's not enough information in the question to understand how to help you. What I am saying is to include the information in the images in the question as well.

Comment: @Justin I have edited my question, now there is more information

Comment: The information in the images is still not in the question. However, it looks like all you have to do now is add `target_link_libraries(MyExecutable Boost::Boost)`

Comment: @Justin Now there are a lot more of errors :( [link](https://i.imgur.com/zZsA8A4.png)

Comment: You need to link the appropriate boost components as well. See the documentation for [FindBoost.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html)

Comment: @Justin I am really sorry, but I don't know how to fix that alone. Do you have some sample code or something like that? I would be very grateful if you sent me that.

Comment: The boost components which are not header only need to be linked with. Thus, you need to tell CMake to link with them. See [the documentation I linked](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html?highlight=add_executable) for more details